# PyGame in Visual Studio - Loading images gives an error, but when I paste the same code to IDLE, it works perfect. Any fixes?

Tags: python, image, pygame

Here's an example of what I'm talking about (taken from an excerpt of my project).

```
####Initial Variables####
TOTAL_NUM_PLAYERS = 121
NUM_COINS = 9999999
PACK_PRICES = {"Six Player Pack": 500, "Two Player Pack": 100, "Seven Player Pack": 600}
GAME_STATE = {"Latest Pack": "N/A", "Number of Players in Latest Pack": 0, "Number of Coins": NUM_COINS, "canClick": True, "displayClub": False}
####

#####Fill array with every player card image using the array PlayerImgPaths#####
AllPlayerImages = []
PlayerImgPaths = ['Images/Players/' + str(i+1) + '.png' for i in range(TOTAL_NUM_PLAYERS)]
for i in range(TOTAL_NUM_PLAYERS):
    AllPlayerImages += [pygame.image.load(PlayerImgPaths[i]).convert_alpha()]
    AllPlayerImages[i] = pygame.transform.scale(AllPlayerImages[i], (156,221))
#####
```

I've been using IDLE for most of this project, but then switched to Visual Studio because it is better for what I'm doing. The problem happened when I changed the `TOTAL_NUM_PLAYERS` variable from `90` to `121` (or anything else). Then every other place where I load an image broke as well. What's weird is that when I copy the exact code back into IDLE, it works no problem. Is there a fix or should I just stay in IDLE?

Comment: Using a relative path is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Based on @MichaelButscher's comment, the path might be wrong. Where is the script relative to the `Images` folder in the Visual Studio solution output files (release/debug) on disk?

Comment: @alexyorkI tried both absolute paths and relative. The 'Images' folder is in the same folder as the main.py file

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe folder is in the same folder as `main.py` but VS may run it in different folder and then relative path can be wrong. You can always use `os.listdir('Images/Players/`)` to see what files see Python in folder.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't exactly specify the case, but if you're running the file *from* VSC, it may not work to the best of its ability. Try to run the file itself.

If this doesn't work, but pasting the code into IDLE does work, you could always-worst case edit in VSC and then copy it into IDLE when you need to test it.

Try giving some more detailed information on your problem, how you produced the error, and what the error is.